# WebSocket's in OpenAPI documentation

Tags: openapi

Based on the following https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/ it seems that we can use `wss://` and `ws://` schemas in OpenAPI documentation.

So, I am just wondering how to represent `requests` and `responses` and the `source of request` because I don't find answers for below points.

- There is nothing like GET, POST in websocket right? Should I assume all as POST?
- `Source of request should` be represented, if it is server or client who is making request to who.
- Not able to find any examples too for the websocket in Open API format or any other format that I am aware of.

Comment: For 1st question, in web socket initial connection establishment will be made through GET call with HTTP and then will be upgraded to WS. This will give us chance to pass headers. Once connection is established then you can only send messages.